# If I am using a port at localhost:portnumber do I need to open that port in the firewall of the server?

Tags: networking, firewall, port

If I am using a port at localhost:portnumber do I need to open that port in the firewall of the server? For example if mysql will only be accessed locally by an application.

Answer (score 1):

If no other computer needs to acces that port, then the iptables rule `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` (or its equivalent with your own firewall) is enough. This rule is part of those always added when you setup a firewall, so you most liekly have it already.

Otherwise, many other applications based on the loopback IP wouldn't work.

Comment: Is that the same for windows? I know windows doesn't use Iptables. So that means that all communication goes through the firewall even internally in the server. If i blocked the loop back address by not having that rule, apps trying to use the loop back address:portnumber would fail.

Comment: AFAIK Windows firewall always unlocks the loopback address, as it is even more useful on Windows than on *NIX (Windows doesn't have Unix sockets). If you open the Resource Monitor to the Network tab and look at the Network Activity frame, you may see a several "IP loopback" lines, especially if you have multiprocess apps running (Firefox or Origin for instance).

Comment: Some apps require an ip address other than the loopback to communicate. So what happens when the app is running on the same server as the nic. Example nic address is 192.168.1.10:4545. I guess I have to open that rule in the firewall even though its local.

Comment: If you use an external address I am not sure. Normally the OS would detetct that the address is local and automatically route the connection to the loopback interface. But why would an app prevent the use of `127.0.0.1` in the first place? It's just another IP address.